# How can I add a configuration page for my slack app?

Tags: slack-api, slack

How can I add a configuration page for my slack app?

example: asana has an add configuration button which leads to a page which we can use to then connect the slack user account with asana account

[image]

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong here, but I think this might be limited to the apps which Slack created themselves in the early stages of "3rd party apps". Note that [the asana app](https://hacklondon.slack.com/apps/A0F81FK1C-asana) doesn't have the `Slack conducts a brief review of apps in our App Directory and does not endorse or certify these apps.` as opposed to for example [the Avabot app](https://hacklondon.slack.com/apps/A1UGG46DB-avabot)

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. Do you know how I can edit the `visit site` link in my app page? I am sandboxing right now, Do I get access to that only after submitting to the app directory?

Comment: that's actually a very good question. Back when I submitted Simple Poll to the app directory there was a field which would take this URL. That seems to be gone now? My best guess is that this gets added in the App Directory approval process.

Answer (score 6):

Several Slack apps (e.g. Twitter, Google Calendar) provide a configuration page after installation into Slack. However this feature seams to be available only to commercial partners of Slack, but not as a standard feature for every app developers.

Developers need to implement it by themselves with an external app / script that is linked the Slack app and store the configurations in their own database.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41081402/how-to-store-configuration-items-in-a-slack-app/41082828#41082828) for a full explanation on how this works.

Looking on the official [Slack Plattform Roadmap for Developers](https://trello.com/b/ZnTQyumQ/slack-platform-roadmap-for-developers) this feature might be implemented in the future under "Install apps from within Slack".

**Update:**

You can now use [Dialogs](https://api.slack.com/dialogs) to create something similar to configuration pages. It allows you to open a custom modal window with up to 5 inputs (text or drop-downs). Its still not the same as having a full configuration page like the internal Slack apps have, but its a huge step forward and might be sufficient for many cases.

Comment: Ok, but I am still going to look around for a while. Because, apps like Giphy or many others have a link  such as `Browse Apps > Giphy > Edit configuration`. Where we can customize our integration.

Comment: Fair enough. If you find anything please share it here, however I doubt you will if you are not a commercial partner of Slack. I have extended my answer to make it more clear why some apps have a config page.

Comment: @Prashanth The Giphy integration was also created by Slack. That's why it has a config page.