# What's the correct way to add custom admin settings/configurations to my Slack Bolt app?

Tags: slack, slack-bolt

I'm building a Slack app using Bolt. This app has certain settings that should only be modified by the Workspace Admin.

Based on the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41209730/how-can-i-add-a-configuration-page-for-my-slack-app), you can't add a "Configurations" page. What is the best options if I can't use a Configurations page?

I looked at Dialogs and Views, but those seem to be intended for use by anyone. As it stands, I'm thinking of using a Dialog with a check to ensure the user requesting it is a workspace admin.