# How do you make a Redirect URI for a Slack App?

Tags: python, redirect, oauth, slack-api, slack

I'm trying to create a Slack App ([see here](http://boas.io)), but I'm having incredible difficulty with how to create a Redirect URI.

Slack states the following:

> You must specify at least one redirect URL for OAuth to work. If you
>   pass a URL in an OAuth request, it must (at least partially) match one
>   of the URLs you enter here. Learn more

I have a rudimentary understanding of a Redirect URI conceptually, but I have no idea how to go about actually getting this Redirect URI that Slack requires.

I've successfully used all of Slacks Integrations with Python including Real Time Messaging, but setting up a Redirect URI seems to require a special server or a website.

Comment: Yup, exactly. It requires a publicly reachable server on your side :)

Comment: Any recommendations on how to set up a reachable server for someone who has never done that

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 5):

As already mentioned in the comments you will need a publicly reachable webserver to host your script for installing the Slack app. So the redirect URL is the URL to your installation script.

Basically any webserver or script hosting service that runs your favorite script flavor  (e.g. PHP or Python) will work. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40996820/generate-slack-app-token-for-slack-application/40997970#40997970) answer on how the OAUTH process can be implemented.

The redirect URL works without SSL, but for security reasons SSL is strongly recommended. Also many other features of Slack requires you to run SSL on your webserver (e.g. [Interactive Buttons](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-buttons))

Another option is to run a webserver on your local machine (e.g. [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) for windows) and open it to the Internet through a secure tunnel (e.g. [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)). For developing and testing this is actually the better alternative, since you can test and fix your Slack app locally without having to deploy every change on a public server.

However for running a public Slack app (e.g. one that is listed on the Slack App Directory) I would strongly recommend to put the production version of your App on a public webserver.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to get it up so that you can authorize another workspace you can always use 'http://localhost' after authorizing it will try to redirect you there and you wont be able to see anything useful, but the authorization should still have taken place I believe.

of course if you're looking for the api code, you will have to pull it directly from the browser url. ... it's very manual.